# What are the disadvantages of using large subnets?

Tags: subnet

Why can't I just use a huge subnet like 10.113.0.0/16 compared to a smaller one like 10.113.0.0/24 ?

I understand that if a network were to use hubs, then this would be a problem, but what about on a network using switches?  I plan to have around 160 computers on the network.

Comment: no, there isn't any real reason to not use a larger network other than that some would call it "wasteful" (which is ludicrous on a private network) or "untailored", and it may limit choices for expansion later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question.

The problem actually exists on a switched network as well as a hub environment.

You have identified Hubs are bad. They are. When a computer sends a packet through a hub, all devices attached to the hub will get the packet This is called flooding (or broadcasting). Switches were invented to fix this problem, they take the packet and send it only to the port that it should go to.

But Switches also Flood! Lets imagine we have just turned our switch on. He knows nothing about the network and his CAM table (List of addresses) looks like this:

```
MAC                 IP              Interface
FFFFFFFFFFFF        10.113.255.255  ----
ABCDEFGHIJKL        10.113.0.25     VLAN
```

The first line represents the broadcast ID, in otherwords how to contact everyone on the subnet. If a packet is sent to that MAC/IP all 65534 clients on the network will get that packet. More on that later. 10.113.0.25 is the switch, he knows himself.

Lets say I plug a PC into port one, and another into port two. When the PCs first send a packet through an interface, the switch will say "SOME ONE NEW!!!" and add that mac address, and its associated IP to his table.

```
MAC                 IP              Interface
FFFFFFFFFFFF        10.113.255.255  ----
ABCDEF123456        10.113.0.25     VLAN
123456894111        10.113.0.100    Port 0
9432721D3C83        10.113.0.101    Port 1
```

Now he knows. But if he doesn't know, Say I want to ping 10.113.0.102 who is in fact attached to another switch then he must send the packet out on all interfaces and pray it reaches the correct destination. Once he has a reply back he can add to his table that 10.113.0.102 replied from his gigabit link port 24 and can add it to the table. After that he can talk send the packet the correct way.

```
MAC                 IP              Interface
FFFFFFFFFFFF        10.113.255.255  ----
ABCDEF123456        10.113.0.25     VLAN
123456894111        10.113.0.100    Port 0
9432721D3C83        10.113.0.101    Port 1
394822DEABD3        10.113.0.103    Port 24
```

Switches will delete information in their table 5 minutes after it was last used, to help ensure up to date information is kept. Whenever a computer asks "Where is 10.113.0.104" and sends an arp message, the switch will flood the message on all ports, and every switch will do this. It reaches its destination and the computer replies and the switches returning the response can add to their tables.

Imagine this on the scale of 65534 devices all asking "Where art thou 10.113.5.194" or sending other broadcasts for various reasons (such as apple play.) It will get too noisy.

The solution is to break down into smaller networks. If we break your 10.113 range into /24 networks (254 hosts) Only 254 hosts will receive any one broadcast. We can put routers or layer 3 switches with VLANs in to make sure we can send information across the subnets, but broadcasts will be contained.

And that is why we use smaller subnets. If you are your own business and have a completely private network you **CAN** do as you wish but you **SHOULD** select your subnet wisely, and include room for growth. For example a /24 would give you a growing room of 94 devices. You can quite often find in Cicso documentation their recommendation of 500 hosts per subnet, I believe Microsoft have a higher quota of 1000 for their recommendation.

Also note that performance problems will only occur with live clients. Having a subnet of 65534 IP addresses is different than having 65534 active devices. If I only have 100 active devices then only 100 devices will be sending and receiving broadcasts, which is manageable.

An analogy for you. I have a hall that fits 200 people, but only put 5 people in it. We can all talk and hear perfectly fine, but if you put 200 people in that room all talking, then there is a lot of background noise.

You may find [this](https://ttcshelbyville.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/why-do-you-subnet/) Interesting.

Comment: Is there any overhead if the subnets have the same number of machines connected?

Comment: Sorry can you clarify so I can answer the right question? What sort of overheads were you thinking there might be?

Comment: You mention that a broadcast on a 16 bit subnet will go to 65534 clients. Does this happen even if there are only a few clients? In other words, is it any worse to have e.g. 50 clients accross a 16 bit subnet vs. an 8 bit one? Or is it just the case that 16 bits allows more clients and more clients is more expensive?

Comment: It will only go to existing hosts. The switches only send data down ports that are active, i.e have something on the other end. So no 50 clients on a 16 vs on a 8 is identical, its only if you were to have 65534 active hosts all broadcasting would you have problems. The physical sepration of subnets is caused by routers, when a router sees a broadcast they do not send it on. I probably should edit my answer to explain that better tommorow.

Comment: @MooseBoys The extra two bits at the end now may be of interest for you, thanks for the idea for improvement!